# How to change the login notice on a custom shell?

Tags: login, command-line, motd

I was trying to setup a custom shell for a temp user.

```
sudo usermod --shell /home/nemo/a temp
```

The contents of a:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Test"
```

Unfortunately, on trying to login as user `temp`, I see this:

```
Nautilus login: temp
Password: 
Last login: Sat Oct 22 01:33:33 IST 2011 on pts/1
Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Test
```

I want to remove the Notice that appears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily disable the printing of the motd with:

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

as documented in [login.1](http://manpg.es/login.1).

Answer (score 1):

You should (at least termporarily) remove/move/empty the file

```
/etc/motd
```

that is a symbolic link to `/var/run/motd`, but this will affect all users.

That file is shown by `login` and is build on every boot from `mounted-run` service, using scripts in the `/etc/update-motd.d/` directory.